# Can you identify this Pinarello model?

Tags: road-bike, identify-this-bike

I am currently eyeing this bike but can't seem to figure out what model it is nor does the current owner. I do know it has Campy Record and the ONDA carbon fork. I am just trying to do my research before I go look at it. Thank you in advance for your help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A better picture would be helpful.  And some close-ups of the front and rear brakes, derailers, etc.

Comment: Have you asked the owner? This is again one of the bikes that have cost thousands of dollars/euros as new, so uninformed sellers are a bit suspicious.

Comment: @ojs Yes. A Pinarello owner who doesn't know the model/year/type of a bike he's selling? It screams 'suspicious' and 'stolen'. And he should be able to provide proof of purchase, be it only for warranty and insurance.

Comment: Also, Pinarello is most certainly one of the bike makers where the serial number is in their database and a valuable piece of information. It should provide details on the first owner and information in case of a declared theft. Ask the current owner for the serial number and check with Pinarello.

Comment: The model name is frequently written on the bike, e.g. the seat or top tubes.

Answer (score 2):

I would also add that the fact that there are so few clear images and there are practically zero “typical” bicycle pictures that identify the bike make it even more suspicious.   There would probably be no question of identifying if there were a few clear pics of the seat tube decals as well as close ups of all the tubes.
It is not a dogma.  Its an 04 or 05 Paris.

Comment: Can you say more about why you think it's not a Dogma? In the pictures I'm finding for the 2005 Paris, the main tubes are blue all the way to the bottom bracket junction. The Cycling News article linked in the other answer features a 2005 Dogma. The tubes at the BB junction are black, just as in the photo provided originally. Clearly, fake Pinarellos exist, but it could also be that the seller does/did not know what he/she had.

Comment: +1 for _"practically zero “typical” bicycle pictures"_ but I have no idea what the model is. Extremely fishy. Would not buy.

Answer (score 1):

2004 Pinarello Dogma Frameset
[Source](http://autobus.cyclingnews.com/giro.php?id=road/2003/giro03/tech/dogma)

Comment: Judging by the paint, this could well be so. I hesitate very slightly because the groupset is late 2000s Record (i.e. post 2005), and the crankset is a late 2000s item also. Of course, the owner could have bought the frameset and groupset separately.

Comment: The 2005 is different paint, a bike that was used could have gotten a new grouppo at anytime due to use or otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Pinarello Dogma AK61 Magnesium

The first and the last Dogma made in Italy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  This does seem like a possibility, but you could improve your answer if you [edit] in some links or pictures to help the asker of the question a better idea of what you're suggesting.

Comment: As DavidW says, this could be improved. I can't judge if it's credible or not even though it sounds plausible